# c++ read function getting extra letter

Tags: c++

```
int main() {

  int len;
  cout<<"Enter the size of dynamic array you want: ";
  cin>>len;

  int file_len;
  int *new_num;

  ifstream in("test.txt");

  in.seekg(0, ios::end);
  file_len = in.tellg();
  in.close();

  if(file_len>len)
  {
    int times= file_len/len;

    for(int i=0; i<times; i++)
    {
        ifstream in("test.txt");
        if(i==0)
        {
            char *n_ch = new char[len];
            in.seekg(0, ios::cur);
            in.read(n_ch, len);
            cout<<n_ch<<"\'";
            delete n_ch;
        } else {
            char *n_ch = new char[len];
            in.seekg(i*len, ios::cur);
            in.read(n_ch, len);
            cout<<",,"<<n_ch<<"..";
            delete n_ch;
        }
    }
    in.close();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is to get the nth to (n+len)th letters and put them into an array, and then print them.

[image: right now I'm getting this result]

right now I'm getting this result,
the content of test.txt is:

```
    ABCDEABCDE
    qwerty poiuy
    zxcvb
    mnbhhg
    ooooo
```

I can't find the reason why I am getting extra letters, which i guess is the first letter of the next letters.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading C strings. C strings are null terminated, that is they need a null character at the end to indicate how long the string is. Your code doesn't do that. Try this

```
        char *n_ch = new char[len + 1]; // one extra for the null terminator
        in.seekg(0, ios::cur);
        in.read(n_ch, len);
        n_ch[len] = '\0';               // add the null terminator
        cout<<n_ch<<"\'";
        delete n_ch;
```

Answer (score 2):

After `in.read(n_ch, len)` you need to use [`gcount()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) to see how many characters were actually read.  Say your file has 37 characters, and you're reading in chunks of 10: the last read will only return 7 characters and you want to make sure you only try to write 7 to the output (you can use `cout.write(n_ch, gcount());`).